# Filter out entries of datasets based on string matching

Tags: pandas, string

I'm working with a dataframe of chemical formulas (`str` objects). Example

```
formula

Na0.2Cl0.4O0.7Rb1
Hg0.04Mg0.2Ag2O4
Rb0.2AgO
...
```

I want to filter it out based on specified elements. For example I want to produce an output which only contains the elements `'Na','Cl','Rb'` therefore the desired output should result in:

```
formula

Na0.2Cl0.4O0.7Rb1
```

What I've tried to do is the following

```
 for i, formula in enumerate(df['formula'])

    if ('Na' and 'Cl' and 'Rb' not in formula):
       
          df = df.drop(index=i)
```

but it seems not to work.

Comment: but the first formula contains `O`, shouldn't it be discarded?

Answer (score 2):

You can use use `contains` with `or` condition for multiple string pattern matching for matching only one of them

```
df[df['formula'].str.contains("Na|Cl|Rb", na=False)]
```

Or you can use pattern with `contains` if you want to match all of them

```
df[df['formula'].str.contains(r'^(?=.*Na)(?=.*Cl)(?=.*Rb)')]
```

Comment: Actually I would like to keep ONLY chemical formulas containing exactly these elements. Everything else should be discarded.

Comment: Exactly that's how it work

Comment: no, your solution will keep in the dataset other chemical formulas which eventually contain other elements apart from specified ones.

Comment: @JamesArten Got your point, updated the solution now it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are unclear, but assuming you want to filter based on a set of elements.

Keeping formulas where all elements from the set are used:

```
s = {'Na','Cl','Rb'}
regex = f'({"|".join(s)})'
mask = (
 df['formula']
 .str.extractall(regex)[0]
 .groupby(level=0).nunique().eq(len(s))
)

df.loc[mask[mask].index]
```

output:

```
             formula
0  Na0.2Cl0.4O0.7Rb1
```

Keeping formulas where only elements from the set are used:

```
s = {'Na','Cl','Rb'}

mask = (df['formula']
 .str.extractall('([A-Z][a-z]*)')[0]
 .isin(s)
 .groupby(level=0).all()
)

df[mask]
```

output: no rows for this dataset

Comment: No I want to keep the fractional quantities, just discarding all the other elements. Also, regarding the entries, If I want, let's say, {'Na','Cl'} then if there is an entry like 'Na0.2Ga0.5Cl0.7' it should be discarded, i.e. I want to keep chemical formulas containing ONLY specified elements.